# External files in Doxygen

Tags: fortran, doxygen

I am currently working on a very big ocean model, and since I am developing a new parametrization, I want to explain it deeply in the documentation of the code. To do this, I am using Doxygen. Of course the documentation I want to provide is long, as it is necessary to explain a lot of details, and I need also a lot of formulas. I am talking about a couple of hundreds of lines of latex formatted text (including formulas) for each module (I am working in fortran90).

Since it seems bad to insert directly all this explanations in the `.f90` source file, I am looking for a valid alternative. To be clear, I want something like the `\input{}` command in LaTex, to refer to an external file that could be possibly containing all my explanation in some suitable formatted text.

```
!----------------------------------------------------------------------
! A VERY BIG GENERAL CIRCULATION MODEL
!----------------------------------------------------------------------
!
! MODULE: tludyn
!
! DESCRIPTION:
!> @brief A novel parametrization of Navier stokes 
!>
!> @details Here goes a long description. This parametrization needs a 
!>  lot of explaining, long formulas, long texts... Let's say that every
!>  subroutine needs a couple of hundreds lines of latex-formatted code
!
!>          \f[
!>              \left( \nabla \cdot A \right)_{i}= \frac{1}{e_{1}e_{2}}
!>                       \left[ 
!>                          \frac{\partial}{\partial i}\left( e_{2}a_{i1} \right) + 
!>                          \frac{\partial}{\partial j}\left( e_{1}a_{i2} \right) + 
!>                       \right] +
!>                    \frac{1}{e_{3}}\left[ 
!>                           \frac{\partial}{\partial k}\left( a_{i3} \right)
!>                    \right]
!>            \f] 
!> @include tlu_dyn.md
!> 
!----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Potentially, I would love to put everything in a file, say `flu_dyn.md` and include sections of this file in different parts of my `.f90` source code. If not possible I would like to just include external files as they are. The included file should appear in the html page.
How can I achieve this?

**Edit 1**
I am using version 1.9.2 and these are the differences with the reference config file:

```
PROJECT_NAME           = DoxyNEMO
CREATE_SUBDIRS         = YES
TAB_SIZE               = 8
OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN   = YES
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = f=FortranFixed \
                         f90=FortranFree \
                         txt=md
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
INPUT                  = release-4.0/src/tlu_dyn.f90 \ (source)
                         release-4.0/src/tlu_dyn.md    (here I want to put 
                                                        the long explanations)
FILE_PATTERNS          = all the usual plus this: *.dox
EXAMPLE_PATH           = release-4.0/src
LATEX_HEADER           = doxy_header.tex
LATEX_FOOTER           = doxy_footer.tex
```

In the file `tlu_dyn.md` there are the same lines from `\f[` to `\f]`.
The result looks like:
[image: this screenshot of the generated html page].

**Edit 2**
The file `tlu_dyn.md`, that contains my pedantic description of the code, is the result of 2 days of trials where I tried several extensions and several commands. In the first example I posted, the file contained exactly what shown in the figure, as I was trying to see if Doxygen syntax was ok. In a second trial, I tried to put two simple lines as

```
# Is this working? (Header)
This is plain text.
```

to see if a tex with markdown syntax was better.
I would like to write in this file in a simple way, so markdown is an option, pure latex would be even better (even though there is no evidence that pure latex is admitted), html or Doxygen syntax are last resorts.

Comment: Just as a side remark: You might want to look into [FORD](https://github.com/Fortran-FOSS-Programmers/ford). It is an alternative to doxygen which is especially suited for Fortran.

Comment: Sometimes it can be easier to have the description in a separate file (also easier for re-use) on the other hand the user of the code (not the user of the documentation) has to switch between different files. Which version of doxygen are you using? Do you get warnings? What kind of problems do you have? Did you have a look at the commands `\include...` and `\snippet...`?.

Comment: Depending on your compiler there is an easy solution: just include it using the preprocessor directive `#include "tludyn.inc"`.

Comment: @albert Yes, I tried both of them. The result is however not what I intended, as in both cases I have the content of the file treated just like code. This means that it is in a box and in monospace font and not processed as a the text in the rest of documentation. Also, if I put an equation there, there is no latex rendering.

Comment: You didn't, yet, answer the question about the doxygen version, but did you try `\include` of `\include{doc}` (`\includedoc`)? For formulas did you use the doxygen syntax for formulas (like `\f$ ...\f$`)? Just add a small example to your question, including the settings used that are different from the default settings (`doxygen -x`).

Comment: @albert I uploaded the changes in my initial post. However, I am now trying ```\includedoc```, this is working better as if I write plain text it is put there with no box and not treated like code. However, I can't figure out how to decide the formatting of my text, as Doxygen syntax, markdown syntax and LaTex syntax does not work

Comment: I see that you use the master version of doxygen. What is in your tlu_dyn.md ? You still include it with `\include` though. When knowing what is in the MD file I might see what the problem is.

Comment: tlu_dyn.md now contains just ```# Is this working? (Header) This is plain text.``` (there should be a line break after closing the parenthesis). It was just to understand what kind of syntax I need to use in external. If I put Doxygen syntax it does not work

Comment: It looks like that you still use `\include` and not `\include{doc}`, though the real problem is that it looks like that doxygen doesn't like the formulas in the included part (nor with `\snippet{doc}`. It looks like formulas are also part of the, cryptic, note in the documentation: When using the {doc} option, some commands like \cond and \if don't work with this command due to the
moment of parsing. (Looks like also the `\latexonly` is an exception...). At the moment I think only direct inlining is the only option.